# SQL Subquery That Joins Table Back On Itself By Referencing Another Table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two tables; a Magazine table which is linked to a Publisher table through a Publisher_ID column shared in both tables.

The Magazine table has a column for categories depending on what the content of that particular magazine is focused on (ie fashion, celebrities, cars, sports, hunting, etc). Many publishers have Magazines that span many categories but some only a few.

I want to run a query where I select the top 100 Magazine titles that are in the "cars" category, and then have have those magazines joined onto their associated publishers, but then select the rest of those publishers' titles regardless if those magazines are cars or not.

ie I want to select all the magazines from the publishers which are joined from the first 100 selected Magazines that are cars focused.

The result I'm hoping for are all the columns from the Magazine and their associated joined Publisher table columns, and should yield far more than 100 magazines including categories more than just "cars" **BUT** only from publishers that have *at least one* magazine title that is in the "cars" category and excluding any publisher (and their associated magazines) which don't publish car magazines.

The query attempt I was working with is here:

```
SELECT Magazine.*,Publisher.*
FROM 
    Magazine
INNER JOIN 
    Publisher
ON
    Magazine.publisher_id = publisher.publisher_id
WHERE (SELECT Magazine.category
       FROM Magazine
       WHERE Magazine.category = 'cars' 
       LIMIT 100)
;
```

the output I got was this

```
Single-row subquery returns more than one row.
```

Sorry for the exposition, but wanted to be as descriptive as I could with what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say how you choose the 100 magazines.  But for 100 *arbitrary* magazines, you can use `IN` or `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT m.*, p.*
FROM Magazine m INNER JOIN 
     Publisher p
     ON m.publisher_id = p.publisher_id
WHERE p.publisher_id IN (SELECT m2.publisher_id
                         FROM Magazine m2
                         WHERE m2.category = 'cars' 
                         LIMIT 100
                        );
```

Comment: So that query runs, but only pulls in 100 rows. I was hoping that whatever the top 100 magazines that have "cars" as a category that it would then pull in *all* the associated magazines from the publishers associated with that subquery.

Comment: @JLuu . . . That makes sense.  The comparison should be on the publisher id, not the magazine id.